# Automatic monitoring of iphone app

Tags: iphone, automation

I would like to setup automatic monitoring of my iPhone app. Say I am logging into the app, checking all features if they are working correctly and logging out of the app and repeating this procedure over and over using some automated process.

Additonally, I would like to send mail notifications incase there is some issue with any functionality  ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, but it's a whole subject to learn and impossible to describe completely in an answer here. You can set up integration tests with Frank/Cucumber/Calabash and then hook it up into a Jenkins or any other CI server. You can make it as complicated as you want (we had a setup where it would record all the outgoing calls with Charles and save it as part of the process to be able to check if anything had gone wrong with the network calls, saved crashlogs symbolicated and mailed them).
Start reading http://www.testingwithfrank.com/
and http://calaba.sh/